# PHP regex : split on unescaped delimiter

Tags: php, regex, escaping

I am able to split strings in the format `key:value;` using the following code:

```
$inside = "key1:value1;key2:value2;key3:value3;";
preg_match_all("/([^:]+):([^;]+);/s", $inside, $pairs);
```

What I would like to do is allow for the occurrence of the colon and semi-colon character in the values by introducing an escape character e.g. `\;` any colon or semi-colon immediately preceded by a backslash would be ignored.

Bonus points if within the same regex, the escaped characters can then be stored in the array of matches unescaped without having to run everything through `str_replace`. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match_all(
    '/(                    # Match and capture...
     (?:                   # either:
      \\\\.                # an escaped character
     |                     # or:
      [^\\\\:]             # any character except : or \
     )+                    # one or more times
    )                      # End of capturing group 1
    :                      # Match a colon
    ((?:\\\\.|[^\\\\;])+); # Same for 2nd part with semicolons
    /x', 
    $inside, $pairs);
```

does this. It doesn't remove the backslashes, though. You can't do that in a regex itself; for this, you'd need a callback function.

To match the final element even if it doesn't end with a delimiter change the `;` to `(?:;|$)` (same for the `:`). And to return empty elements as well change the `+` to a `*`.

Comment: Thanks Tim. That works pretty well. What in your opinion would be the most efficient way to remove any escaped characters in the array of matches?

Comment: Note that if the string doesn't end with a delimiter the last element will not be found. I've edited the answer to include how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$inside = "key\:1:value\;1;key2:value2;key3:value3;";
$pairs = preg_split('/(?<!\\\\);/',$inside,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY );
foreach($pairs as $pair) {
        list($k,$v) = preg_split('/(?<!\\\\):/',$pair);
        // $k and $v have the key and value respectively.
}
```

[**See it**](http://codepad.org/VTrRIWbV)

Comment: This works until you find escaped backslashes in the string: `key1\\:value1\\;` etc. Probably not a problem, but who knows.